# extract word from middle or end of line using in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I know there are hundreds of similar posts out there and I have tried a lot of things but am not able to get it. I want to extract one word from a string starting the `-D`. Example:

```
This is foo -Dbar,barOne the end
```

should print

```
-Dbar,barOne
```

Here is what I have:

```
sed -n 's/.*\-D\(.*[\s\|$]\)/\1/p'
```

This is not the only regex, I have tried a lot of variations of this but one or the other doesn't work. Example, once I was able to get the output if `-D` was the last word but didn't work it was in the middle and once it worked if it was in the middle and didn't if it was at the end. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pure BASH:

```
s='This is foo -Dbar,barOne the end'
[[ "$s" =~ (-d[^[:space:]]+) ]]; echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
-Dbar,barOne
```

#### Explanation:

- `-d` match literal `-d`
- `[^[:space:]` - match anything BUT space
- `[^[:space:]]+` match 1 or more of non-space (equivalent of `\S+`)
- `(-d[^[:space:]]+)` capture whole match in captured group #1
- `&&` perform next command only when previous is successful
- `echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` print captured group #1

Comment: Am a bash noob, a little elucidation would be awesome.

Comment: I added explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

this may help you:

```
kent$  echo "This is foo -Dbar,barOne the end"|sed 's/.*\(-D\S*\).*/\1/'
-Dbar,barOne
```

Comment: @Kent. Nice use of the meta character "\S"..totally forgot about this char.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
awk '/-D/' RS=" " file
-Dbar,barOne
```

A `gnu awk` version (due to multiple characters in RS)

```
awk 'NR==2 {print RS$1}' RS="-D" file
-Dbar,barOne
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.

```
sed -n '/-D/{s/.*-D/-D/;s/ .*$//;p}'
```

1. `/-D/` only match lines with `-D`
2. `{` start a command group
3. `s/.*-D/-D/` remove anything up to the -D
4. `s/ .*$//` delete everything after the first space
5. `p` print the line